# NavigationBar Image on iOS 6.1 too large

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

In my app, I have custom navigation bars using images.  I load them up in viewWillAppear like so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIImage *gradientImage46 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar2.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:gradientImage46 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

On iOS 7, this is fine, but I just noticed on 6.1, the bar is much too large and looks like this:
[image]

Thoughts as to what's happening?

Comment: what are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: may be you need to resize the image with nav bar width. and its best to call super on the first line.

Comment: Wow...must have forgot to resize the image before I put it in there...it was way too big. The size is now fixed, but I just noticed it is covering up the back buttons